# How to properly lock/unlock camera when drawing on SurfaceView?

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality, surfaceview, android-camera

I created an Activity with Augmented Reality functionality. Part of that is to have phone camera display in the background (which is SurfaceView in Activity layout).

in activity onCreate() method I do:

```
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
```

My callbacks are:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}
```

Right now when I close my application (while leaving it in the background) Camera app is not working because Camera is still locked inside my app.

How should I implement activity onResume() onPause() methods in order to lock/unlock camera?

Also leaving camera locked in the app takes up about 5% of CPU on Galaxy S and after I come back to my app - it crashes in surfaceChanged() when trying to camera.startPreview();

Help!

Comment: Solved. Thanks for not paying attention and letting it to do on my own.

Comment: You're welcome! I love not paying attention.

Comment: You should post your solution to help any future developers with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like this to surfaceCreated callback:

```
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
    }
    camera = Camera.open();
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

And then inside onPause() add release and call to callback:

```
    camera.release();
    surfaceCreated(surfaceHolder);
```

Now it works like a charm! Cheers!

Comment: Apparently surface is destroyed each time I close the app leaving it in background. So next time I reopen it, I need to create surface again and start drawing camera output on it. Hope it helps!